# Visual Web Developer and multiple sites on the same FTP server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ftp, visual-web-developer

I used Visual Web Developer to open up Website_A directly through FTP, which was real nice.  It let me edit the files on my computer and then save them right up to the server so I could see the effects my changes were having immediately.  This is just like what I used to do with UltraEdit on non .Net sites, but with the added benefit of the Intellisense, Solution Explorer, etc.

Anyway, that worked great, but when I was done I went to open Website_B the same way.  But both sites are on the same FTP server.  Despite using different usernames and passwords, I still get the Website_A's files when I try to open Website_B.

Has anyone run into this problem with opening two different sites that use the same FTP server?  Is there a way around it?  I tried renaming the project folders/files that were created in C:\Users\George\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects, but that didn't seem to help.  The only thing that seemed to work was deleting the project folders and starting over.  Any ideas for a better way to handle multiple sites with one FTP server?  I can't find anything on the web…

Thanks,

George J.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the FTP server via DNS (as opposed to an IP address) you can probably use a subdomain that points to the same FTP server.

If the DNS record is set up to allow for infinite subdomains, then you could connect to  for website A and  for website B.

Visual Web Developer should assume that FTP servers on, what appears to be, different servers would belong to different web sites when in fact only the folder is different.

I do not have visual web developer so I can't test this, but FireFox could not tell that ftp://1.example.com was the same as ftp://2.example.com

Comment: That's not going to work. Our company name is the domain and the sub domain identifies the particular server: ftp://ftpws18.mycompany.com

Comment: Will ftp://websitea.ftpws18.mycompany.com work? Subdomains can go on for a while.